# Shared preferences in mono android

Tags: xamarin.android

Hello I am new to mono android I want to use shared preferences for saving Login details in my application

someone please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting File for android applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740060/setting-file-for-android-applications)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To repeat my [answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740060/setting-file-for-android-applications/13758706#13758706)...

Retrieve:

```
var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("MyApp", FileCreationMode.Private);  
var somePref = prefs.GetString("PrefName", null);
```

Store:

```
var prefEditor = prefs.Edit();
prefEditor.PutString("PrefName", "Some value");
prefEditor.Commit();
```

Comment: I needed to add a prefEditor.Commit(); line after the PutString command to make the value stick.